# Создание экземпляра (instance) класса

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется несколько классов, метод одного из которых должен создать список экземпляров другого

```
class b:
    /..

class a:
    self.list1 = []
    def add_units(self, clas, num):
        for i in range(num):
            self.list1.append(?)
a.add_units(b, 3)
```

Каким образом можно создать экземпляр класса(причем не один), зная лишь его имя?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я немного поправил Ваш код. Получилось вот так:

```
class b:
    x = 5

class a:
    list1 = []  # При объявлении свойства класса self не применяется
    def add_units(self, clas, num):
        for i in range(num):
            self.list1.append(clas())  # Создаём экземпляр класса clas, вызывая ()

A = a()  # Необходимо создать объект класса, чтобы вызвать его нестатический метод

A.add_units(b, 3)

print(a.list1[1].x)
```

В консоль выводится `5`.

Теперь подробнее: Чтобы создать экземпляр любого класса, достаточно вызвать для него конструктор с помощью оператора `()`.

Python тем и привлекателен, что в аргументы функции можно передать что угодно, вплоть до типа данных. Таким образом, мы просто вызываем конструктор любого типа данных, переданного в функцию, и в список помещается объект, созданный этим конструктором.